# ipywidgets.embed missing dependencies? Key error when run in venv

Tags: python, google-maps, ipywidgets

I am writing a script that simply asks the google api for the latitudes and longitudes for a list of addresses read in from a csv file and outputs an html with the googlemap widget embedded.  Further I hoped to run pyinstaller in order to make this into a .exe.

Running the code on my original conda environment it works fine however the .exe that pyinstaller creates is *massive* for such a small script (*over 300mb*).  As such, I created a new virtual environment in which to work and have installed what I believe to be the bare minimum packages necessary and have rewritten the code to use as few packages as I am able which for the currently working portion of the code dropped it down considerably to just over 10 mb.  (*No numpy or pandas for me... ah well*).

The code again works fine up until the final step:

```
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html
embed_minimal_html("exporttest.html", None)
```

The above line should take any widgets, in particular the figure created from

```
fig = gmaps.figure(layout=figure_layout)
markers = gmaps.marker_layer(coordinates)
fig.add_layer(markers)
fig
```

Running the currently modified version in my original conda environment with all my of my usual packages installed this runs as expected without errors.  Running on the virtual environment however on the mentioned lines I get the following key error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\synod_environ\lib\sre_parse.py in 
parse_template(source, pattern)
   1020                 try:
-> 1021                     this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
   1022                 except KeyError:

KeyError: '\\u'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3359941239ab> in <module>
      1 from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html
      2 
----> 3 embed_minimal_html("exporttest.html", None)

...

error: bad escape \u at position 0
```

(*For clarification, key error has two slashes before the u, some frustration in getting this to post correctly*)

As the code runs correctly in the one environment but not the other, I can only assume that I'm missing a package somewhere that ipywidgets requires, but running `pip check` doesn't notify me of anything missing.

`pip list` returns the following packages:

```
altgraph           0.16.1
backcall           0.1.0
bleach             3.0.2
certifi            2018.10.15
chardet            3.0.4
colorama           0.4.0
decorator          4.3.0
defusedxml         0.5.0
entrypoints        0.2.3
future             0.17.1
geojson            2.4.1
gmaps              0.8.2
idna               2.7
ipykernel          5.1.0
ipython            7.1.1
ipython-genutils   0.2.0
ipywidgets         7.4.2
jedi               0.13.1
Jinja2             2.10
jsonschema         2.6.0
jupyter            1.0.0
jupyter-client     5.2.3
jupyter-console    6.0.0
jupyter-core       4.4.0
macholib           1.11
MarkupSafe         1.0
mistune            0.8.4
nbconvert          5.4.0
nbformat           4.4.0
notebook           5.7.0
pandocfilters      1.4.2
parso              0.3.1
pefile             2018.8.8
pickleshare        0.7.5
pip                10.0.1
prometheus-client  0.4.2
prompt-toolkit     2.0.7
Pygments           2.2.0
PyInstaller        3.4
python-dateutil    2.7.5
pywin32-ctypes     0.2.0
pywinpty           0.5.4
pyzmq              17.1.2
qtconsole          4.4.2
requests           2.20.0
Send2Trash         1.5.0
setuptools         40.4.3
six                1.11.0
terminado          0.8.1
testpath           0.4.2
tornado            5.1.1
traitlets          4.3.2
urllib3            1.24
wcwidth            0.1.7
webencodings       0.5.1
wheel              0.32.2
widgetsnbextension 3.4.2
wincertstore       0.2
```

Any thoughts on how to further identify what went wrong, what package might be missing or how to fix the issue, and/or alternate ways to save a googlemaps output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddling with it and comparing from one environment to the other, I found that my virtual environment had ipywidgets 7.4.2 while the base environment had ipywidgets 7.2.1.  Downgrading versions fixed the issue I was having.